Sequelize (with NextJS) sync() twice
I am using Sequelize with nextjs. During the DELETE operation, it performs sync() twice. Is this a problem or is it normal?
I am sharing my codes below.
// sequelize.ts
import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize-typescript';
import { Person } from './models/person';
import * as _mariadb from 'mariadb';

export const sequelize = new Sequelize({
  dialect: 'mariadb',
  dialectModule: _mariadb,
  database: 'nextjs',
  username: 'root',
  password: 'xyz',
  models: [Person]
});

sequelize.sync()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Database & tables created!');
  })
  .catch(error => console.error('Sequelize initialization error:', error));

//routes.ts
import { Person } from "@/app/database/models/person";
import { sequelize } from "@/app/database/sequelize";


export async function GET(_request: Request, {params}: {params: {id: string}})
{
    await sequelize.authenticate(); // without that getting error: ModelNotInitializedError: Model not initialized: Member "findOne" cannot be called. "Person" needs to be added to a Sequelize instance.
    const testData = await Person.findOne({where: {id: parseInt(params.id)}});
    return Response.json(veri);
}

export async function DELETE(request: Request, {params}: {params: {id: string}})
{
    const index = await Person.findOne({where: {id: parseInt(params.id)}});
    const testData = index?.username;
    index?.destroy();
    return Response.json(testData);
}

And here this logs:
Executing (default): SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_NAME = 'Person' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'nextjs'
Executing (default): SELECT 1+1 AS result
Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `Person` FROM `nextjs`
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `username`, `password`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `Person` AS `Person` WHERE `Person`.`id` = 5;
Database & tables created!
Executing (default): DELETE FROM `Person` WHERE `id` = 5
 DELETE /comments/5 200 in 284ms
Executing (default): SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_NAME = 'Person' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'nextjs'
Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `Person` FROM `nextjs`
Database & tables created!

Problem: Database & tables created! seems two times.
I tried change orm query like;
await Person.findOne({where: {id: parseInt(params.id)}}).then(x => x?.destroy());
but problem not about it.
Then i tried return new Response("x"); instead of return Response.json(); but not about it.

calling sync() twice is unnecessary especially when working with large databases, to prevent this only call it at the start of your application/server and remove the unnecessary call from request or route handlers and make sure to remove any conditional logic that would trigger it again.

Hello, is there any example for it or tutorial?
